# Elastic Search check if object has a key x and matches some crieteria

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

So I am working on a generic Elastic search method. I can generate queries well but I need to find a way to check if a document has property x, it must match a value y

something like;

```
{
  index: 'any-index',
  query {
    bool: { must: [...queries] },
   // if has property companyId, only return objects with companyId == 4
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a filter with [exists-query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.3/query-dsl-exists-query.html) can be a solution.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "field_name"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "field_name": "xpto"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```